# How to send data to observer class or plugin class when click on check box in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, onepage-checkout, checkbox

i am trying to send the data to observer or plugin through check on checkbox but its not firing.can anyone help me how to send data to observer class or plugin by clicking on check box.

Comment: If checkbox is checked, then only u get the value. U should get in Request Param. Check for name is Unique within Form

Comment: i want to override tax value in order summary when i check the checkbox.

Comment: You should send checkbox value in `additional_data` from your payment ui component.

Comment: on check only i want to reload the data and override the tax value.